# jplayer: playing a mp3 from a link on page

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer

I have a Html template which uses jplayer, i know how to add an existing playlist in the player but dont know how to make it play through a link on a page.

the theme's link is: http://themeforest.net/item/musik-music-web-application-template/7831557

I tried to contact the developer but he's not active and does not reply. please help,.!

also, i checked the comments, there he asked to put a “data-jp-src” attribute on a link.

```
  <a href="#" title="musician" data-jp-src="a.mp3">play</a>

$(document).on('click', '[data-jp-src]', function(e){
  e && e.preventDefault();
  var music = {};
  music.title  = $(this).attr('title');
  music.mp3 = $(this).attr('data-jp-src');
  myPlaylist.add(music);
  myPlaylist.play(-1);
});
```

i dont understand this

Comment: This code should play the mp3 file, you put on data-jp-src

Comment: how to put it,.I am beginner at this, usually I use wordpress,.but need to work on this html theme this time,. can you tell me in detail how to do it,. it'll be really helpful,. and thanks for your response,.!!

Comment: We don't write a code here. This code you can put in any html that you have access to. I'm not sure why you do this when you don't understand basic programing principes. You can use any programer to do that.

Comment: ok,. this means all this code has to go in a html file,.. not  in a javascript file or else,.

Comment: Dude <a href="#" title="musician" data-jp-src="a.mp3">play</a> is html, you can't put it in js file

Comment: ok i understand,..what should i save the .js file as,.?? name of the js file

Comment: suppose i want to load file "www.mp3.com/audio.mp3" in the player,.. what should d code look like,.??

Answer (score 1):

Open file js/jPlayer/demo.js

add code like this:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.jp-play-me', function(e){
    e && e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(e.target);
    if (!$this.is('a')) $this = $this.closest('a');

    $('.jp-play-me').not($this).removeClass('active');
    $('.jp-play-me').parent('li').not($this.parent('li')).removeClass('active');

    $this.toggleClass('active');
    $this.parent('li').toggleClass('active');
    if( !$this.hasClass('active') ){
      myPlaylist.pause();
    }else{
      var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 7 - 1));
      myPlaylist.play(i);
    }
   });

   $(document).on('click', '[data-jp-src]', function(e){
    e && e.preventDefault();
    var music = {};
    music.title  = $(this).attr('title');
    music.mp3 = $(this).attr('data-jp-src');
    myPlaylist.add(music);
    myPlaylist.play(-1);
   });
```